# Getting the last modified date of a file in C

Tags: c, date, file-io, compiler-errors

I want to get the last modified date of a file in C. Almost all sources I found use something along this snippet:

```
char *get_last_modified(char *file) {
    struct tm *clock;
    struct stat attr;

    stat(file, &attr);
    clock = gmtime(&(attr.st_mtime));

    return asctime(clock);
}
```

But the `attr` doesn't even have a field `st_mtime`, only `st_mtimespec`. Yet, when using this my Eclipse tells me that `passing argument 1 of 'gmtime' from incompatible pointer type` on the line `clock = gmtime(&(attr.st_mtimespec));`

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm developing on OSX Snow Leopard, Eclipse CDT and using GCC as Cross-Platform compiler

Comment: Yes, otherwise `stat` itself wouldn't be available.

Comment: Although OT: You do not want to store away the reference returned by `get_last_modified()` won't you? `asctime()` returns a reference to static memory, which's content will be overwritten on each successive call to it.

Comment: It's only called once, but I will keep it in mind should that ever change :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On OS X, `st_mtimespec.tv_sec` is the equivalent of `st_mtime`.

To make this portable, do

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#ifndef st_mtime
#define st_mtime st_mtimespec.tv_sec
#endif
#endif
```

and then use `st_mtime`.

Comment: Is there any way to make this cross compilant? The program has to run on Ubuntu without any warnings and errors, but I don't have a VM to program on...