# How do I reliably retrieve a file's last modified time on OS X?

Tags: macos, stat, last-modified

I'm experiencing a problem on OS X, where `stat` intermittently returns a struct whose `st_mtime` has a value of 0, for certain files.

Why does this happen, and is there any alternative function that will provide me with a reliable modified date for a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Objective-C, NSFileManager has a nice API named ["`attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsfilemanager_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfItemAtPath%3aerror%3a) where one of the things passed back in the NSDictionary object is ["`fileModificationDate`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/fileModificationDate).

You also can use CoreFoundation CFURL functions, like ["`CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey) which has something called ["`kCFURLAttributeModificationDateKey`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Common_File_System_Resource_Keys) which you can get the value of.

Comment: I'm using C++, but I'm pretty sure I can use this as a last resort.

Comment: Then CoreFoundation functions might be easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know their reliability, but what about `ls -l` or `find -ls`?

**EDIT:**

I just found this: [Getting the last modified date of a file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373505/getting-the-last-modified-date-of-a-file-in-c)

> On OS X, `st_mtimespec.tv_sec` is the equivalent of `st_mtime`.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound silly, but check the return code of `stat()`. If it returns anything but zero, there was an error (e.g., file not found).

I just spent a few hours tracking this down myself.