# How to get last modified time of a file in OS X/ C?

Tags: c, macos, date, unix

I have the following code:

```
struct stat info;
stat("/Users/john/test.txt", &info);
printf("%s\n", ctime(&info.st_mtimespec));
```

in which I am trying to get the last modified time of the file as displayed in the `ls -l` command in the format:

```
Jan 29 19:39
```

Unfortunately, above code doesn't work.I get the following error message on xcode:

```
Conflicting types for ctime
```

How can I fix it ? If there any alternative approaches to get the time in format mentioned, please do mention.

Comment: It "doesn't work" because?

Comment: I get a "conflicting type" error message for the ctime function

Comment: Don't you think it would make sense to mention that in the question? Please edit your question to put in the exact error message.

Comment: Jenna, you'd be surprised at how often the error message provides some hint as to what problem is occurring.

Comment: @ghoti I understand the problem-ctime is not getting the arguments it needs. What I am having trouble with is what to plug-in to the thing....

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, **a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Possible duplicate: 
[Getting the last modified date of a file in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373505/getting-the-last-modified-date-of-a-file-in-c)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala There is a "desired behavior": I want the time format expressed as given in the example : Jan 29 19:39....

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the **complete** output from the compiler, because you've omitted some of it. Copy and paste it. Do not retype it.

Comment: When @AnttiHaapala comment was made all you had was "it doesn't work". Which is not a *specific* problem or error.

Comment: @robmayoff I am on xcode - when I type above, I get the red exclamation with the above message. I will paste the entire code, if it helps( which is just the main declaration)...

Comment: Open the Issue navigator (View > Navigators > Show Issue Navigator; default shortcut: ⌘4). Open all of the disclosure triangles to show all of the compiler messages. Select all of the messages (click one message and choose Edit > Select All). Choose Edit > Copy to copy them to the pasteboard. Edit your question here on stackoverflow and paste in the messages.

Comment: when calling the function `stat()`, always check the returned value, because there are many things that can cause the `stat()` function to fail,

Answer (score 0):

Checking on [struct stat](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/stat.htm)'s declaration you'll see that `st_mtimespec` must be `st_mtime`.

Then, basing on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673226/how-to-print-time-in-format-2009-08-10-181754-811), I rearranged your code like this:

```
struct stat info;
struct tm* tm_info;
char buffer[16];

stat("/Users/john/test.txt", &info);
tm_info = localtime(&info.st_mtime);
strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%b %d %H:%M", tm_info);

printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct stat info;
    stat("sample.txt", &info);
    printf("%.12s\n", 4+ctime(&info.st_mtimespec));
    return 0;
}
```

Output( same as time field of `ls -l`):

```
Feb  4 00:43
```

(This was for a random file on my computer).

Answer (score 0):

does your code have:

```
#include <time.h>
```

also, the `ctime()` function expects the passed parameter to be a POINTER to a `time_t`.

Here is the struct pointed to by the `stat()` function:

```
          struct stat {
           dev_t     st_dev;     /* ID of device containing file */
           ino_t     st_ino;     /* inode number */
           mode_t    st_mode;    /* protection */
           nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
           uid_t     st_uid;     /* user ID of owner */
           gid_t     st_gid;     /* group ID of owner */
           dev_t     st_rdev;    /* device ID (if special file) */
           off_t     st_size;    /* total size, in bytes */
           blksize_t st_blksize; /* blocksize for filesystem I/O */
           blkcnt_t  st_blocks;  /* number of 512B blocks allocated */
           time_t    st_atime;   /* time of last access */
           time_t    st_mtime;   /* time of last modification */
           time_t    st_ctime;   /* time of last status change */
       };
```

Notice that none of the fields are a `st_mtimespec`

perhaps you meant `st_mtime`

Note: your running OS-X and I'm running linux,  but the OS-X should have the very same definitions of field names.